# Ubuntu & PyCharm 2022.1 suddenly stop working the keyboard shortcuts

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

Suddenly PyCharm 2022.1 stop working all keyboard shortcuts.
Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a lot to solve that, this is the reason I am sharing the solution:

For some reason, PyCharm does not recognize the shortcuts if you are with the Caps Lock on.

Just press it again and Pycharm will get back working with the shortcuts.